# Laravel Count Different Value From a Table

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have tables name applications and status. The tables as follow:

Table: applications:

| id | status_id | is_active |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | true |
| 2 | 1 | true |
| 3 | 1 | true |
| 4 | 2 | true |
| 5 | 2 | true |

Table: status:

| id | desc |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | completed |
| 2 | pending |
| 3 | processed |
| 4 | failed |

I'm trying to count the applications base on status. The expected output I want in blade:

| Status | Total |
| --- | --- |
| All | 5 |
| Completed | 3 |
| Pending | 2 |
| Processed | 0 |
| Failed | 0 |

I am using eloquent in my controller to get the count, but i have to make different variable for each status.

```
$total = Application::select('*')
         ->where('is_active', 'true')
         ->count();

$complete = Application::select('*')
            ->where('application_sts', 1)
            ->where('is_active', 'true')
            ->count();
```

Is there any simple way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```php
Status::select(DB::raw('status.id, status.desc, COUNT(*) AS count'))
        ->join('applications', 'status.id', '=', 'applications.status_id')
        ->groupBy('status.id')->get();
```

Or this way:

```php
DB::table('applications')->select(DB::raw('status.id, status.desc, COUNT(*) AS count'))
           ->join('status', 'status.id', '=', 'applications.status_id')
           ->groupBy('status.id')->get();
```

Comment: These work well. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can have a base query and then apply only what's changing, this way you won't repeat the same code every time:

```
$query = Application::select('*')
         ->where('is_active', 'true');

$total = $query->clone()->count();

$complete = $query->clone()->where('application_sts', 1)->count();
```

Please note that you must clone the `$query` since this is not an immutable objet